# Accessing result value of a function inside another async function in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I start learning angular with typescript for a while and now I face a situation that I couldn't figure out how I should solve. I have two methods in a class **method A** and **method B**. Both of them send a request to the database to receive some information. the problem is when I call **method B** inside **method A** the value that I receive from **method B** is not updated, it shows me the value for the previous call, how I can overcome this situation so when I call **method B** in **method A** it shows me the fresh result.

```
@Injectable()
export class foo{
   id: number;

   async method_A(){
     this.method_B();
     console.log(this.id);   // in here after I call method_B it should show me the correct value 
                             // but it will show me the value for previous call to database.
     await this.http.get<any>("url").subscribe(data => {})
   }

   method_B(){
      this.http.get<any>("url").subscribe(data => {
         this.id = data.id;
      })
   }
}
```

things that I tried so far:

First, I used **await** when I call the **method_B** but it doesn't work.

Second, I tried to use a **BehaviorSubject** and assign the **id** in it and return it as an **asObservable** and subscribe to it inside **method_A**, but still the result is not what I want. in this case, the method will call twice and the first time the value is the old value, and the second time it will return the updated value which is not useful for me because in another file I always receive the value from the first time call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue in `method_A` *after* `method_B` got the result, then you should return a promise from `method_B` to await in `method_A`. You can convert an observable to a promise with [`toPromise`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/topromise) which will help you do that:

```
method_B() {
    return this.http.get<any>("url").toPromise()
}
```

Then you can await that result in `method_A` and assign `this.id` there:

```
async method_A(){
    const { id } = await this.method_B();
    this.id = id;
    console.log(this.id); // This should be up-to-date now
}
```

Comment: I tried the exact same thing but it shows me **undefined**, also I am wondering if I need to subscribe in method_B to do other things besides assigning value to **id** how I am suppose to do that?  because we can't use "toPromise()" after "subscribe()".